# Oracle SQL Query tuning

Tags: sql, oracle

Can we tune the below oracle sql query? This query takes a lot of time to fetch rows from the db.

```
SELECT T.ACCUMULATORS_INFO ACCU_INFO, T.SUBSCR_NO service_internal_id, 
T.SUBSCR_NO_RESETS service_internal_id_resets, T.*,T.MTR_TYPE_ID MTR_TYPE, 
T.ACCOUNT_NO account_internal_id, T.MTR_SUB_TYPE_ID MTR_SUB_TYPE, 
T.FILE_ID EXTRACT_FILE_ID, T.UNIT_TYPE_ID unit_type, RCV2.ISO_CODE PREV_SUBSCRIBER_CURRENCY, 
T.MTR_SOURCE_ID MTR_SOURCE, RCV1.ISO_CODE SUBSCRIBER_CURRENCY 
FROM  MTR T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE_CURRENCY_REF RCV1 ON (T.CURRENCY_CODE = RCV1.CURRENCY_CODE) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE_CURRENCY_REF RCV2 ON (T.PREV_CURRENCY_CODE = RCV2.CURRENCY_CODE) 
WHERE (T.CURRENCY_CODE IS NULL OR RCV1.service_version_id = ?) AND 
(T.PREV_CURRENCY_CODE IS NULL OR RCV2.service_version_id = ?) AND 
T.mod_date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND T.subscr_no = ? AND 
T.subscr_no_resets = ? 
ORDER BY T.mod_date DESC
```

Regards,
Chandra

Comment: Please show us the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

It is always difficult to optimize a query without knowing the model and the data, but this is what I would try.

You should at least have an index on
`rate_currency_ref (currency_code, service_version_id )`
and maybe one on
  `mtr (mod_date, subscr_no, subscr_no_resets)`.

I would also adjust the query to get the additional conditions into the `LEFT JOIN`s for better readability (and maybe better optimization).

```
SELECT T.ACCUMULATORS_INFO ACCU_INFO, T.SUBSCR_NO service_internal_id, 
  T.SUBSCR_NO_RESETS service_internal_id_resets, T.*,T.MTR_TYPE_ID MTR_TYPE, 
  T.ACCOUNT_NO account_internal_id, T.MTR_SUB_TYPE_ID MTR_SUB_TYPE, 
  T.FILE_ID EXTRACT_FILE_ID, T.UNIT_TYPE_ID unit_type, RCV2.ISO_CODE PREV_SUBSCRIBER_CURRENCY, 
  T.MTR_SOURCE_ID MTR_SOURCE, RCV1.ISO_CODE SUBSCRIBER_CURRENCY 
FROM MTR T 
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE_CURRENCY_REF RCV1
     ON (T.CURRENCY_CODE = RCV1.CURRENCY_CODE AND RCV1.service_version_id = ?)
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE_CURRENCY_REF RCV2
     ON (T.PREV_CURRENCY_CODE = RCV2.CURRENCY_CODE AND RCV2.service_version_id = ?)
WHERE
  T.mod_date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND T.subscr_no = ? AND 
  T.subscr_no_resets = ? 
ORDER BY T.mod_date DESC
```

Comment: Did you try to adjust the query? Can you please show the execution plan?

Comment: Did you gather your table stats [(see here)](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbms_stats_gather_table_stats.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

The SQl looks weird at   `...(CURRENCY_CODE      IS NULL OR service_version_id_RCV1 = ?)`

Anyways, assuming SQL is functionally correct and not performing well despite index suggested by 'Peter', I would tune and re-write SQL like (using sub-query) to allow optimizer pick a better plan:-

```
SELECT tmp.*
FROM
  (SELECT T.ACCUMULATORS_INFO ACCU_INFO,
    T.SUBSCR_NO service_internal_id,
    T.SUBSCR_NO_RESETS service_internal_id_resets,
    T.*,
    T.MTR_TYPE_ID MTR_TYPE,
    T.ACCOUNT_NO account_internal_id,
    T.MTR_SUB_TYPE_ID MTR_SUB_TYPE,
    T.FILE_ID EXTRACT_FILE_ID,
    T.UNIT_TYPE_ID unit_type,
    RCV2.ISO_CODE PREV_SUBSCRIBER_CURRENCY,
    RCV2.service_version_id_RCV2,
    T.MTR_SOURCE_ID MTR_SOURCE,
    RCV1.ISO_CODE SUBSCRIBER_CURRENCY,
    RCV1.service_version_id_RCV1
  FROM MTR T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE_CURRENCY_REF RCV1
  ON (T.CURRENCY_CODE = RCV1.CURRENCY_CODE)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN RATE_CURRENCY_REF RCV2
  ON (T.PREV_CURRENCY_CODE = RCV2.CURRENCY_CODE)
  WHERE T.mod_date BETWEEN ? AND ?
  AND T.subscr_no        = ?
  AND T.subscr_no_resets = ?
  ) tmp
WHERE (CURRENCY_CODE      IS NULL OR service_version_id_RCV1 = ?)
AND (PREV_CURRENCY_CODE   IS NULL OR service_version_id_RCV2 = ?)
ORDER BY mod_date DESC
```

I would suggest to keep following indexes on MTR, RATE_CURRENCY_REF as well:

1. mtr (mod_date, subscr_no, subscr_no_resets)
2. mtr (CURRENCY_CODE)
3. mtr (PREV_CURRENCY_CODE)
4. rate_currency_ref (currency_code)

Comment: The optimiser is going to eliminate that subquery, and it's highly unlikely that any difference in the explain plan would occur. I can't think of a situation where introducing a subquery in this fashion is going to change the plan.